# Split and recombine stdin in Bash script

Tags: bash, redirect, stream, pipe, tee

Say I have streaming text data coming in to my Bash script, with one record per line, and I want to append to each line some function of that line and spit that to `stdout`:

```
record1      record1  fn(record1)
record2  ->  record2  fn(record2)
...          ...
```

This would be relatively easy to do with, say, Awk. However, say the function I'm applying to my input data is orders of magnitude more efficient if it's applied to streamed data (and I've got a lot of it, so the linewise Awk processing is definitely not an option). This is the solution I've come up with:

```
input="$(mktemp)"
trap "rm -rf ${input}" EXIT
cat > "${input}"
paste "${input}" <(some_function "${input}")
```

This works by redirecting `stdin` into a temporary file (the `cat` line), then `paste`ing the files together, using process substitution. However, this seems a bit messy to me (e.g., UUOC) and I'm thinking there's probably a "better" way to do it with `exec` (for redirection) and `tee`, but I'm not really sure how.

Could this be done better?

Comment: `fn(recordX)` is the result of calling `fn` with `recordX`

Comment: Assume even if you could read multiple lines from stdin from one-shot, but you want the output to be written per record (unique per line) right? In which case, processing one line at a time is definitely needed? don't you think

Comment: Yes, in that sense, but my point is that `some_function` in my above is much faster if applied to the whole stream rather than being invoked line-by-line. To make this more concrete: `some_function` here is extracting a field from the input, then base64 decoding it, then classifying that on some criteria. The base64 decoding step is the bottleneck if it's run line-by-line; with a bit of trickery, it can be run on streaming data to get the same results and it runs in minutes rather than hours/days... My above solution works perfectly, I'm just wondering if there's a better/nicer way.

Comment: Yes in total-agreement of your point on the read side, but the point is your write logic is unique by each line right? you cannot do a bulk write at each unique line? makes sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. My solution computes the values of `fn(record1)` to `fn(recordN)` and then `paste` puts them back together. The nature of the POSIX streaming/buffering keeps them in lock-step, which is effectively a "bulk write", but I don't see the relevance of this point to my question.

Comment: If you need to capture the input and then send all of it to the function, try this which does not use a temp file: `data=$(cat); paste <(echo "$data") <(some_function "$data")`

Comment: I do question why "some_function" is more efficient in bash with the entire input rather than line-by-line in awk. There's a bit of a smell there...

Comment: @glennjackman For example, `some_function` could be doing a DB lookup. It's generally more efficient to write a query to produce the entire output, rather than a query that does one record at a time...plus, not to mention, the time it takes to invoke the querying tool and make a connection. It's very slow with Awk's `command | getline` idiom. As for slurping everything into a variable, I don't see that as any nicer than my original. Also bear in mind that my input data stream is on the order of GiBs. I'm sure there's a way that redirection and `tee` can be used, but I'm probably wrong :P

Answer (score 0):

## Simple (?) Workaround

The easiest solution would probably be to modify your function such that its input is always printed before its actual output. Mathematically: Replace `f(x)=y` with `g(x)="x f(x)"`

Use one of the following approaches if you cannot modify your function easily.

## File-less Approach

If you have enough memory, you can modify your current approach to work without files by saving stdin to a variable:

```
input="$(cat)"
paste - <(yourFunction <<< "$input") <<< "$input"
```

## Actual Answer

**EDIT:** *This may not work for large files. `tee` may interleave both outputs. I'm working on a better solution. I don't know whether I will find a better one. Feel free to edit this answer if you found a modification making this approach safe.*

```
(tee >(yourFunction) | pr -Ts --columns 2)
```

The first part prints stdin followed by stdin piped through your function. Basically the same thing as `cat file <(yourFunction < file)` would do if the input was given as the file `file`.

The second part works as `paste  1st_half_of_output  2nd_half_of_output`.

#### Example

Assume the following three lines were given as stdin

```
Lorem Ipsum
What a nice 2nd line
\t\r\n[]().*?+<>\
```

and your function was

```
f() { awk '{print "#" NR}'; }
```

Then `tee >(f)` would print (**EDIT:** *There is no guarantee on the order. See note from above.*)

```
Lorem Ipsum
What a nice 2nd line
\t\r\n[]().*?+<>\
#1
#2
#3
```

And `pr` would convert that output to

```
Lorem Ipsum #1
What a nice 2nd line    #2
\t\r\n[]().*?+<>\   #3
```

Before each `#` there is a tabulator as column delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't remove the need for a temporary file, but it at least gets rid of the useless use of `cat`:

```
input="$(mktemp)"
trap "rm -rf ${input}" EXIT
tee "${input}" | paste - <(some_function "${input}")
```

Comment: n.b., While this works, it doesn't work for large data sets. It seems to fail when it reaches the pipe buffer size, so `cat` it is.